# Trig Question Lemma Application

Tags: trigonometry

A trigonometry lemma states that if $a^2+b^2=1$, then there exists an angle $\theta$ such that $a=\cos\theta$ and $b=\sin\theta$.  This lemma is the converse of $a=\cos x$, $b=\sin x$.

I am then given an application question, which looks something like this:

> Suppose angle $\alpha$ is less than 45 degrees, $a=\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha$, and $b=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$.  Show that there is an angle $\theta$ such that $a=\cos\theta$ and $b=\sin\theta$.

How I'm seeing it:

Take these two, square them, and add them.  If they give 1, that means there does exist an angle like that.

Expanding $(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)^2$, we get $\sin^4\alpha+\cos^4\alpha-2\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha$.

From $(2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)^2$, we get $4\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha$.

Adding these two, we get $\sin^4\alpha+\cos^4\alpha+4\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha$.

When I enter this into Mathematica, I get a value of 1, yet I don't know how to reduce this expression to get 1.  How do I know it's 1 for sure?  I'm trying to progress though trigonometry using a trigonometry book and I just don't know how to simplify this sum.

Help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In your expansion of $(\cos^2\alpha - \sin^2\alpha)^2$ where does the term $4\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha$ come from?

Comment: I totally didn't see that, I got mixed up. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you add your revised expressions, you get $\sin^4\alpha + 2\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha + \cos^4\alpha$.  Try factoring it.